# Change domain aggregate to SQL statement

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I strongly need to change this code to a sql normal subquery:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF("D", "DLAST(opendate)", "Table1", "ItemId=1 and opendate is not null", "DLAST(closedate)", "Table1", "ItemId=1 and closedate is not null");
```

How can I do that?!!

Comment: That SQL attempt makes no sense. Edit question to show sample data and desired output as text tables.

Comment: I'm usiing it right now. It returns day differences between two dates of one single Table for an item. But i prefer to do it with subquery. Sth like : Select datediff ("d", select last(closedate).....,select last(opendate) ....

Comment: Did you copy/paste that SQL? Looks like quotes and parentheses in wrong location.

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
SELECT DateDiff("d", Last(OpenDate), Last(CloseDate)) 
FROM Table1 
WHERE ItemId = 1
```

Perhaps:

```
SELECT DateDiff("d", Last(OpenDate), Last(CloseDate)) 
FROM Table1 
WHERE ItemId = 1 AND OpenDate Is Not Null AND CloseDate Is Not Null
```